# Using mobile data causes unexpected results

Tags: javascript, android, ios, httpclient, appcelerator

we are currently working on an application that works fine with wifi and has an offline version and once they have finished the user can upload the results to the online database. The issue were experiencing is that so of the ids are not matching up when using mobile data (3G/4G). Has anyone else experienced this similar problem using HTTPClient, below is an example of my httpclient, am i missing something that will help prevent this or any other suggestions?

I know NETWORK_ENABLED will still perform the sync as mobile data is under the NETWORK_ENABLED, but is there a way to see if connection is lost?

```
this.sendToServer = function(params, httpParams) {
    if (Alloy.Globals.NETWORK_ENABLED){
        var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient(params);
        xhr.validatesSecureCertificate = false;
        xhr.open('POST', this.url, true);
        xhr.send(httpParams);
    } else {
        params.onload();
    }
};
```

Comment: have you used success and error callbacks?

Comment: @renepot yes i have added success and error callbacks i just feel they're not 100% reliable. I probably need more validation of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can recommend is this module here: https://github.com/benbahrenburg/Pinger
But I've never used it. Checking the example .js file, seems to only ping www.apple.com and give you a "yes" or "no".
Could be quite useful actually =)

Comment: Thanks i will check it out and let you know my findings